# What should be returned when a property does not have a value in a REST api?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, rest, express

When there is no value assigned to a property, should it be returned as null or REST API should entirely skip such properties?

Consider an example of user object which has first_name and last_name. (In the below example, last_name need not be an empty string specifically. Consider it was never received from the end user.)

```
{
   first_name: "Bob",
   last_name: "",
}
```

Now since the client is aware of User schema, should last_name be returned or simply dropped from response so that client can automatically set a default value.(i.e empty string `""`)

In case null has to be returned, does it make sense to return null when it has got a special meaning in some cases.(i.e `null` means something and different from `undefined`)

Comment: `last_name: ""` has also a special meaning. It means it has a value and the value is an empty string. `null` means it has no value.

Comment: You should return `null`. `undefined` is not good as JSON does not have that concept

Comment: @Justinas Agreed. Undefined is not an option. Would it make sense to have this type definition on client `last_name: string | null` ?

Comment: There are no type definitions in JavaScript and in TypeScript you would use `last_name?: string`.

Comment: Is the actual question if an API should return `null` or `undefined` under certain occasions on specific properties, or if a property should be skipped if null or empty or undefined? I simply ask because those are different questions.

Comment: @PeterDarmis It's the latter one. Should we skip the property if there is no value associated with it.

Answer (score 5):

My personal opinion to this would be to skip/omit the field, if no data present. If you would had to send hundreds of MB in this `JSON` then it would count a lot.

Also don't forget that your client should always have in mind and **CHECK** the data coming from the API up to a point. To check if a key exists in an array of keys is most easy in numerous programming languages out there.

Having in mind that you should validate the type of the information that comes from the API (int,string, object etc), it would save that part, if the key not exists in the response.

If by any chance you need a key to have a null value if not present in the API response, the above does not mean that you can not add it when you validate the API response. You still would have `LESS` things to compute, making this more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

`undefined` should not be intentionally used if you want to express a missing value. For that we have `null`. The definition of... well nothing.
Im pretty sure thats why rfc4627 includes null.

> JSON can represent four primitive types (strings, numbers, booleans,
> and null) and two structured types (objects and arrays).

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627

It also indicates that you intentionally emitted `null` and that the value is not missing due to an internal error.

In the end this strongly depends on who is consuming this API.
If they know the specs, i think it's ok to go with `undefined`

Comment: The question is "Should we skip the property if there is no value associated with it or return NULL as its value instead? undefined is definitely not an option since it is not valid in JSON.

Comment: It should not be skipped in my opintion and i clearly stated why. `undefined` = skip

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how you define your schema for the API. For example, if Swagger is used to define the API schema(spec), it allows you to specify the required fields that have to be present leaving rest of the fields optional. For example, in the below Error object, code and message fields always have to be returned by the service as they are defined as required. Client using this schema would always expect these fields and would program accordingly.

```
  schemas:
    # Schema for error response body
    Error:
      type: object
      properties:
        code:
          type: string
        message:
          type: string
      required:
        - code
        - message
```

So if lastname is defined as required in your API specification then never allow the user to enter a blank value in the first place. But in a case where the user is allowed to NOT enter any value in the field lastname, define your API spec. in a way where lastname is optional. If lastname is optional, then have the field populated in the response when there is value present else don't return the field in the response.

Answer (score 0):

In golang's `Marshall` function, the approach is that you will have `last_name: ""` in the JSON, **unless you explicitly choose** to omit the empty value from the JSON encoding.

I think this general concept & approach seems reasonable whatever technology your server-side is in.

Quoting https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal

> Struct values encode as JSON objects. Each exported struct field becomes a member of the object, using the field name as the object key, unless the field is omitted for one of the reasons given below.
>
> The encoding of each struct field can be customized by the format string stored under the "json" key in the struct field's tag. The format string gives the name of the field, possibly followed by a comma-separated list of options. The name may be empty in order to specify options without overriding the default field name.
>
> The "omitempty" option specifies that the field should be omitted from the encoding if the field has an empty value, defined as false, 0, a nil pointer, a nil interface value, and any empty array, slice, map, or string.
>
> //SNIP
>
> ```
> // Field appears in JSON as key "myName".
> Field int `json:"myName"`
>
> // Field appears in JSON as key "myName" and
> // the field is omitted from the object if its value is empty,
> // as defined above.
> Field int `json:"myName,omitempty"`
> ```